# Is it true to conclude that there are 4 types of **output** we can reference to a file in Linux?

Tags: io-redirection, stdout, stderr

Is it true to conclude that there are 4 types of **stream output** we can reference to a file in Linux, if we don't want them to appear in the CLI after executing their command?

### Possible references to a file:

1. All stream output
2. Only stderr
3. Only stdout (including stdout's final result).
4. stdout and stderr (excluding stdout's final result).

---

### Notes:

An example for number 4 might be `find / -type f -name php.ini 2>/dev/null`. As I understand, with this command we get no stderr, and no stdout (besides the **stdout's final result** which in this case is the file we searched for, if it was found).

Comment: When you use `2>/dev/null`, you are redirecting only stderr. Bash never redirects a stream only partially.

Comment: In addition to the corrections already given, I would like to point out that this is not “in Linux” this is a Unix or Gnu thing (it is done in the shell). Linux is just the kernel (and before someone points out that the kernel is involver, note this is true for everything that the computer does).

Comment: This is a very oddly worded question. What do you mean by “reference”?  Do you mean [“redirect”](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/159513/80216 "What are the shell’s control and redirection operators?")?  And what do you mean by “stdout’s final result”?  As Kusalananda says in [his answer](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/358022/80216#358086), this is not a standard Unix/Linux/bash phrase; if you [Google it (in quotes)](https://www.google.com/#q=%22stdout%27s+final+result%22), you will find *this question* and *nothing else*.  If you’re going to make up terms, you should define them. … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  As zondo [commented](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/358022/80216#comment633769_358022), the example command you give, `find / -type f -name php.ini 2>/dev/null`, is an illustration of option 2: only stderr is being redirected. *All* the stdout from that command goes to the screen (or whatever the *shell’s* stdout is). Reiterating and reinforcing what zondo said, there is no concept in the shell of sending the last line of a “stream” one place and the rest someplace else (although this can be done with complicated constructs involving other programs).

Comment: Yes - redirect. I exampled the "stdou's final result" but the answers clarified that in the end.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two output streams connected to each process on a Unix system: *standard output* (stdout, file-descriptor 1) and *standard error* (stderr, file-descriptor 2).  These may be redirected independent of each other. *Standard input* uses file-descriptor 0.

- To redirect standard output  to the file `file`, use `>file` or the more explicit `1>file`. Replace `file` by `/dev/null` to discard the data.
- To redirect standard error to the file `file`, use `2>file`.
- To redirect standard error  to wherever standard output is going, use `2>&1`.
- To redirect standard output  to wherever standard error is going, use `1>&2`.

There is no concept "the final result" of a stream or process.  I suppose whatever is sent to standard output may be taken as the "result" of a process, unless it also outputs data to some file it opens by itself or has other side-effects (like unlinking a file from a directory, in the case of `rm`, or handling a number of network connections, in the case of `sshd`).  A process also returns an exit status (zero for "success" and non-zero for "failure") which could be seen as "the result" of that process, but this is not necessarily related to the output streams of the process.

Streams may also be redirected in *append mode*, in which means that if the redirection is to a file, that file will not initially be truncated, and any data on the stream will be appended to the end of the file. One does this by using `>>file` instead of `>file`.

In the note in the question, the command

```
find / -type f -name php.ini 2>/dev/null
```

is given.  This redirects (discards) *only* standard error. The standard output stream is not redirected at all and will therefore be visible, in its entirety, in the console or terminal. If it was an intermediate part of a pipeline, the standard output stream would be fed into the standard input of the next command in the pipeline.

So to conclude, I'd say that there are *two* (not four) output streams. These may be redirected independently in various ways, which includes discarding their contents.

Comment: There is a small return value, an number. It is used to indicate success (0), or failure (another number). It is not displayed on the screen.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor Did some rewriting just now.

Answer (score 3):

Every *process* can use, by convention, three standard file descriptors.  These file descriptors are available as streams: `stdin`, `stdout`, and `stderr`.

By default, when you start a process from a shell (CLI) the first is connected to the input of your terminal (or terminal emulator like xterm), and the other two are connected to the output of your terminal.

You can instruct the shell to redirect them elsewhere, for example to `/dev/null` (where they just get swallowed up). And you can do that independently for `stdout` and `stderr`. So for this case, there are indeed four possibilities:

```
command 
command > /dev/null
command 2> /dev/null
command > /dev/null 2> /dev/null
```

But nothing prevents you from redirecting either or both elsewhere:

```
command > /tmp/myout 2> /tmp/myerr
```

In that case, you will also get no output in your terminal, but you can read it later in the files `/tmp/myout` and `/tmp/myerr`.

Comment: The "terminal" is not the same as the "shell". It's the shell that sets up the redirections. The terminal has no concept of them. The terminal may also run a program which is _not_ a shell at all, e.g. with `xterm -e mutt`.

Comment: @Kusalananda: That's exactly why I wrote *terminal*. Stdin, stdout, stderr are connected to the *terminal*, both when you invoke a command from the shell , and when you do `xterm -e mutt` etc. They are never connected to the *shell*. The *shell* can set up redirections upon invoking commands using the syntax examples given (but actually all programs can do that when invoking other programs).

Comment: @dirkt: Kusalananda is right; you are confusing the issue by artificially narrowing the scope of your statement, and then using nomenclature that is correct only in that narrowed context.  The user could run `cmd1 > out1; cmd2` in a script run by `cron` (or, perhaps, by system startup, a daemon, or by `ssh` *without* the ```-t``` option), and both programs would have stdin and stderr connected to the stdin and stderr, respectively, *of the shell*, and `cmd2` would have stdout connected to the stdout *of the shell*, with no terminal being involved. … (Cont’d)

Comment: (Cont’d) …  If a process gets stdin, stdout and/or stderr connected to a terminal, it’s because it inherited that file descriptor/stream from the shell that started it (or, potentially, by some more obscure and less common mechanism).  The CLI case is a special case of the general case, and should be handled as such.

Answer (score 0):

The situation is simpler, and more complicated,
than your question would suggest. 
To paraphrase what [Kusalananda](//unix.stackexchange.com/users/116858/kusalananda) says in [his answer](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/358022/80216#358086),
there are two standard (conventional) I/O streams (file descriptors)
that are conventionally configured and used for output:
stdout (file descriptor 1) and stderr (file descriptor 2). 
Our canonical question,
[What are the shell's control and redirection operators?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/159513/80216#159514),
discusses how to redirect them. 
Naïvely, we can enumerate five distinct combinations:

```
╔══════════════════════════════╦═════════════════════════════════════════════╗
║                              ║                   stderr                    ║
║                              ╟─────────────────────┬───────────────────────╢
║                              ║       default       │                       ║
║                              ║ (same as the shell) │       redirected      ║
╠════════╤═════════════════════╬═════════════════════╦═══════════════════════╣
║        │       default       ║                     ║                       ║
║        │ (same as the shell) ║          1          ║           2           ║
║        ├─────────────────────╠═════════════════════╬═══════════════════════╣
║ stdout │                     ║                     ║ 4. redirected         ║
║        │                     ║                     ║    to the same file   ║
║        │      redirected     ║          3          ╟───────────────────────╢
║        │                     ║                     ║ 5. redirected         ║
║        │                     ║                     ║    to different files ║
╚════════╧═════════════════════╩═════════════════════╩═══════════════════════╝
```

but if you count `/dev/null` as being different from a file,
and append mode as a special case,
and read-write mode as being different from write-only mode,
and pipes as being different from files,
then the number of combinations increases exponentially. 
However, as stated repeatedly,
“stdout’s final result” is not a standard Unix/Linux/bash phrase.

#### Only two?

The other answers (perhaps wisely) restricted themselves
to stdout and stderr (file descriptors 1 and 2). 
I (recklessly?) believe that a complete answer to this question
should address the fact that other file descriptors are available —
up to hundreds, thousands, or even [over a million](//stackoverflow.com/q/1212925/3960947#1213069). 
For example, if you run a command like `diff file1 file2`,
the `diff` program will open `file1` and `file2`,
and the kernel will probably assign file descriptors 3 and 4. 
The difference is that only file descriptors 0, 1 and 2 are pre-defined. 
Redirecting file descriptors higher than 2
is discussed in the following places:

- [Bash Reference Manual: Section 3.6 Redirections](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Redirections.html)
- [Advanced Bash-Scripting Guide: Chapter 20. I/O Redirection](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html)
- [Difference between 2>&-, 2>/dev/null, |&, &>/dev/null and >/dev/null 2>&1](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/70963/80216) (U&L question)
- [Can we have more file descriptors other than the usual stdin/stdout/stderr (0, 1, 2) ones?](//stackoverflow.com/q/8903612/3960947) (Stack Overflow question)

For example, see this example of a high file descriptor:

```
$ cat canine.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

main()
{
        int     i, len;
        char    msg[] = "Hello, dog.\n";

        len = strlen(msg);
        i = write(17, msg, len);
        if (i == len)
                printf("Success!  i = %d = len\n", i);
        else if (i == -1)
            {
                printf("Error!  i = %d (len = %d)\n", i, len);
                perror("");
            }
        else
                printf("Unexpected result: i = %d, len = %d\n", i, len);
}

$ make canine
cc     canine.c   -o canine

$ ./canine
Error!  i = -1 (len = 12)
Bad file descriptor

$ ./canine 17> animal
Success!  i = 12 = len

$ ls -l
total 70
-rw-r--r-- 1 myusername mygroupname    12 Apr 12 13:36 animal
-rwxr-xr-x 1 myusername mygroupname 67067 Apr 12 13:36 canine
-rw-r--r-- 1 myusername mygroupname   358 Apr 12 13:36 canine.c

$ cat animal
Hello, dog.
```

Warning: I’m not sure that the above will work
for all versions of all shells.

Standard programs don’t write to file descriptors higher than 2
(unless they got that file descriptor from the kernel
by opening a file, making a network connection, or something like that). 
But, if you have a (non-standard) program that does that,
you can redirect those file descriptors.

And, if you have a mere 100 file descriptors,
and you consider only whether each one is redirected or not,
you have over a nonillion (1,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000,000)
possible combinations.